# Scheme 2 minimum values for huffman BST

Tags: tree, scheme, racket, binary-search-tree, huffman-code

Ok so say i was given a list of pairs containing the letter, and its frequency-or the number of times it was seen in a text. ex '((#\a . 4) (#\b . 2) (#\c . 9)) how do i find the 2 lowest frequencies so i can combine them into a tree? Is there some kind of function that would help me find these?

Comment: You haven't accepted a single answer in all your previous questions, please click in the check mark to the left of the best answer in _all_ of your questions.

Comment: Smells like homework.  Try at least sketching out a basic program and come back with questions when you hit problems.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at section [§2.3.4](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.4) in the [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) book, there you'll find a complete explanation on how to implement a Huffman encoding tree from scratch.

Regarding the question, here's one possible way to find the two lowest frequencies in a list with the specified format:

```
(define frequencies '((#\a . 4) (#\b . 2) (#\c . 9)))

(take
 (sort frequencies
       (lambda (x y)
         (< (cdr x) (cdr y))))
 2)

=> '((#\b . 2) (#\a . 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Only using an unsorted list representation of the frequencies is probably not the right approach to this problem.  Here's why: finding the minimum, repeatedly, is the main operation for computing the Huffman encoding tree.  You don't want to keep searching through the whole list as you repeat this min-finding operation.

As a first attack at the problem: consider sorting as an approach to make finding the minimum a fast operation.

However, for this particular problem, you should probably consider using a binary [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), which is a data structure that represents a collection.  It has the really cool property that pulling the minimum element out of a heap is very cheap.  You'll be ending up putting in new elements into your collection during the Huffman tree construction process.  You don't want to keep resorting the list over and over.

Racket has an implementation of binary heaps in its standard library, in the [data/heap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Binary_Heaps.html) collection.  The application of it towards Huffman tree construction is fairly straightforward.  The following implements the basic algorithm with heaps:

```
(require data/heap)

;; ...

;; make-huffman-tree: (listof leaf) -> node
(define (make-huffman-tree leaves)
  (define a-heap (make-heap node<=?))
  (heap-add-all! a-heap leaves)
  (for ([i (in-range (sub1 (length leaves)))])
    (define min-1 (heap-min a-heap))
    (heap-remove-min! a-heap)
    (define min-2 (heap-min a-heap))
    (heap-remove-min! a-heap)
    (heap-add! a-heap (merge (+ (frequency min-1) (frequency min-2))
                             min-1 min-2)))
  (heap-min a-heap))
```

where the free variable `node<=?` is intended to know how to compare by frequency, and `merge` is intended to take two things and put them together.

You can see the heart of the Huffman tree-construction in `make-huffman-tree`: use the heap to pull out two minimal elements, merge them together, and put the result back into the heap.  Repeat until we're left with a single tree.